# .NET Framework Application Development 70-536

Tags: c#, msdn

I'm studying for the 70-536 exam, which is about application development for the .NET framework.

I've bought a book to help me study, this book includes a CD which has test exams on it. Taking on the exam I encountered the following question:

> Given the following C# code sample,
>   how could you display the contents of
>   the host string in the
>   `ProcessDnsInformation` method?

Code sample:

```
AsyncCallback callBack = new AsyncCallback(ProcessDnsInformation);
string host = Console.ReadLine();
Dns.BeginGetHostEntry(host, callBack, host);
```

And then I had 4 options and *only one* could be the correct answer(A, B, C, D):

```
static void ProcessDnsInformation(IAsyncResult result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.AsyncState);
}

static void ProcessDnsInformation(IAsyncResult result)
{
    Console.WriteLine((string)result.AsyncState);
}

static void ProcessDnsInformation(IAsyncResult result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
}

static void ProcessDnsInformation(IAsyncResult result, string host)
{
    Console.WriteLine(host);
}
```

I went for A, because C and D are obviously wrong. To my surprise A was also wrong, the program told me the correct answer should've been B. Which answer would you pick as correct, and why?

Comment: After practice test you can view explanations to every question, why answer is correct and why is wrong

Comment: You poor bastard. That book is full of errors. Even the second edition together with the errata just cover less than 25% of all the errors in the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming result.AsyncState is declared as an object but actually contains a string, then I would say that both A and B are both correct.

But if you are only allowed one correct answer, then you pick the one which is best and I would say that, in general, if you are returned an object, you would normally cast it back to its actual type before using it. In some cases you **have** to do that because the function you are calling will not accept an object, or because you need to access one of its properties, and so I guess this is probably why they reckon B is the 'correct' answer.

I have not done this particular exam, but I have done another Microsoft exam and I found quite a few of the questions fell into the subjective category where I had to pick one out of two answers neither of which I really considered better.  In the end, if you do enough practice tests, you learn what answer they want.